# How to change button color on click in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, boolean

I have a complex codereview exercise where I don't really understand what should I do.

My main question is, how to get a VACCINE button on CLICK green, or red? so if I click once, it will be green with a text: VACCINATED, if I click once more, it will be red with a text: NOT VACCINATED, and so on, for every click it changes itself. I already tried to use some other options, as Angular, but we cannot use it, cause we did not learn it yet. So we can use just JS/ typescript. I would need a proper correction and a function for that but I can't get it.

```
class Animals {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    size: string;
    vaccine: boolean;
    image: string;
    constructor(name: string, age: number, gender: string, size: string, vaccine: boolean, image: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.size = size;
        this.vaccine = vaccine;
        this.image = image;
        array.push(this);
    }
    displayInfo() {
        return `
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card card-decoration" style="width: 22rem;">
                <img src="${this.image}" class="card-img-top" style="height:25rem; object-fit:cover">
                <div class="card-title text-center bg-dark text-white p-1">${this.name}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text"><strong>Gender:</strong> ${this.gender}</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><strong>Age:</strong> ${this.age}</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><strong>Size:</strong> ${this.size}</p> 
                  <h1 class="text-center btn d-flex justify-content-center bg-${this.vaccine?"success":"danger"}">${this.vaccine?"Vaccinated <img src='../pics/tnailup.png' class='iconica'>":"I need vaccine <img src='../pics/tnaildown.png' class='iconica'>"}</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>`;
    }
}

class dogs extends Animals {
    breed: string;
    trainingSkills: string;
    URLbreed: string;
    constructor(name: string, age: number, gender: string, size: string, vaccine: boolean, image: string, breed: string, trainingSkills: string, URLbreed: string) {
        super(name, age, gender, size, vaccine, image);
        this.breed = breed;
        this.trainingSkills = trainingSkills;
        this.URLbreed = URLbreed;
    }

    displayInfo() {
        return `
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card card-decoration" style="width: 22rem;">
                <img src="${this.image}" class="card-img-top" style="height:25rem; object-fit:cover">
                <div class="card-title text-center bg-dark text-white p-1">${this.name}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Gender:</strong> ${this.gender}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Age:</strong> ${this.age}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Size:</strong> ${this.size}</p>
                    <h1 class="text-center btn d-flex justify-content-center bg-${this.vaccine?"success":"danger"}">${this.vaccine?"Vaccinated <img src='../pics/tnailup.png' class='iconica'>":"I need vaccine <img src='../pics/tnaildown.png' class='iconica'>"}</h1>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Breed:</strong> ${this.breed}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Training Skills:</strong> ${this.trainingSkills}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Breed info:</strong> 
                    <a href="">${this.URLbreed}</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>`
    }
}

class cats extends Animals {
    breed: string;
    furColor: string;
    URLbreed: string;
    constructor(name: string, age: number, gender: string, size: string, vaccine: boolean, image: string, breed: string, furColor: string, URLbreed: string) {
        super(name, age, gender, size, vaccine, image);
        this.breed = breed;
        this.furColor = furColor;
        this.URLbreed = URLbreed;
    }

    displayInfo() {
        return `
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12  d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card card-decoration" style="width: 22rem;">
                <img src="${this.image}" class="card-img-top" style="height:25rem; object-fit:cover">
                <div class="card-title text-center bg-dark text-white p-1">${this.name}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Gender:</strong> ${this.gender}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Age:</strong> ${this.age}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Size:</strong> ${this.size}</p>
                    <h1 class="text-center btn d-flex justify-content-center bg-${this.vaccine?"success":"danger"}">${this.vaccine?"Vaccinated <img src='../pics/tnailup.png' class='iconica'>":"I need vaccine <img src='../pics/tnaildown.png' class='iconica'>"}</h1>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Breed:</strong> ${this.breed}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Fur color:</strong> ${this.furColor}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><strong>Breed info: </strong>
                    <a href="">${this.URLbreed}</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>`
    }
}

let array: Array < Animals > = [];

new cats("Arthur", 2, "Male", "Small", true, "../pics/arthur.jpg", "Scottish Shorthair", "Mackerel-Tabby color", "https://www.dailypaws.com/cats-kittens/cat-breeds/british-shorthair");
new cats("Rosie", 2, "Female", "Small", true, "../pics/rosie.jpg", "Sphynx", "Skin", "https://www.thesprucepets.com/sphynx-cat-4176530");
new cats("Linda", 1, "Female", "Small", false, "../pics/linda.jpg", "Angora Shorthair", "White", "https://www.hillspet.com/cat-care/cat-breeds/turkish-angora");
new dogs("Billie", 3, "Male", "Large", true, "../pics/billie.jpg", "German Shepherd", "yes", "https://www.k9web.com/breeds/black-german-shepherd/");
new dogs("Oliver", 2 , "Male", "Small", false, "../pics/oliver2.jpg", "Dachshund", "yes", "https://www.hillspet.com/dog-care/dog-breeds/dachshund");
new dogs("Robert", 5, "Male", "Large", true, "../pics/robert2.jpg", "American Pit Bull Terrier", "no", "https://www.hillspet.com/dog-care/dog-breeds/american-pit-bull-terrier");
new Animals("Black Jack", 1, "Male", "Small", false, "../pics/jack black.jpg");
new Animals("Melissa", 1, "Female", "Small", false, "../pics/melissa.jpg");


(document.querySelector(".sorting") as HTMLElement).addEventListener("click", agesort);


function agesort() {

    array.sort(function (min, max) {
        return min.age - max.age
    });
    (document.querySelector(".result") as HTMLElement).innerHTML = "";
    cards();
};



 



function cards() {

    array.forEach((val) => {
        (document.querySelector(".result") as HTMLElement).innerHTML += val.displayInfo();
    });
}
cards();
```

Comment: You've pasted a bunch of code, but it's not clear what you are trying to do or how your code doesn't get you there. When you run that code how does the result differ from what you want? Please read these to learn more about how to ask a question that can actually be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh sorry, I am quite new here. So the problem is, or my main question is, how to get a VACCINE button on CLICK green, or red? so if I click once, it will be green with a text: VACCINATED, if I click once more, it will be red  with a text: NOT VACCINATED, and so on, for every click it changes itself. I already tried to use some other options, as Angular, but we cannot use it, cause we did not learn it yet. So we can use just JS/ typescript. I just need the function for that.  Hope it is easiest now to understand. :) Thank you!